# Change the extension of a URI in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, url-routing

I am making an API in PHP.

I want to add `.json` to the URL like this:

```
www.example.com/data.json
```

I am using CodeIgniter.
I have tried solving this in routes config file like this

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'data';
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;
$route['/data.json'] = "/data/index";
```

Comment: Do you want to add it to all controllers or only specific ones?

Comment: I want to add it to specific controllers

Answer (score 0):

You can add a url suffix in CodeIgniter by going to the `config.php` file and changing `url_suffix`:

```
$config['url_suffix'] = '.json';
```

This will make your website accesible via `www.example.com/data` and `www.example.com/data.json`

Check the [documentation](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html#adding-a-url-suffix)

If you want to enable it in some pages only you can use the routes like this:

```
$route['data.json'] = 'data/index';
```

If it's a page with dynamic path for example `data/some-id.json` use this:

```
$route['data/(:any).json'] = 'data/index/$1';
```

Comment: Thanks that worked for me... But what if I want to add them to specific controllers...

Comment: @SaadAmir check the updated answer. If you found the answer helpful feel free to [accept it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235)

Comment: -Actually the second-way one does not work... But the first one is working like charm...

Comment: @SaadAmir Updated, remove the `/` from the start.